# Problems with OSX command line wildcard

Tags: macos, bash, shell

Using bash shell in Mac OSX

I've been trying to write a short shell script to take care of part of my compilation process, however when I'm trying to run the script on every file, the wildcards seem to not be acting like I would expect them to.

The script is as follows:

```
rm *.cs
rm *.bin
protoc -I. *.proto -o*.bin
mono protogen -i:*.bin -o:*.cs
```

Now, when I hand-type this at the command line for each file, it works fine. However, when run through this shell script using wildcards, it winds up creating "*.bin" and "*.cs", rather than individual .bin and .cs files for each of my different inputs. Am I misusing wildcards, or is something just going weird?

Comment: Please post your script in its entirety and you'll probably get a better answer.

Comment: Hint: shell parses line by line, whats left for you at the third line? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like (not tested):

```
protofiles="*.proto"
rm *.cs
rm *.bin
for i in $protofiles; do
binfile=${i/.proto/.bin}
protc -I. $i -o$binfile
done
binfiles="*.bin"
for i in $binfiles; do
csfile="${i/.bin/.cs}
mono prtogen -i:$i -o:$csfile
done
```

Anyway... I suggest you to use Makefiles for this job. Try something like this (not tested):

```
CSFILES=a.cs b.cs d.cs e.cs

clean:
        rm *.cs *.bin

%.bin: %.proto
        protoc -I. $< -o $@

%.cs: %.bin
        mono prtogen -i:$< -o:$@

all: $(CSFILES)
```

Comment: Your answer would be even better with a quick explanation to your solution or the problem you saw and solved.

Answer (score 2):

Wildcards don't work like that. They just get replaced by the list of existing matching filenames. So if you rm *.bin, then *.bin matches nothing in the next statement. They do not magically "capture" the replaced value from another token in the same command line.

In bash, the result would be that *.bin remained unaltered, so it should create the file *.bin, not .bin. But you may be using a different shell.

You could accomplish this task easily with make, by the way.